# Is there a convenient way to translate a "from A import B as C" to an python import using a specific path

Tags: python, python-import

I want to import a python module without adding its containing folder to the python path. I would want the import look like

```
from A import B as C
```

Due to the specific path that shall be used, the import looks like

```
import imp
A = imp.load_source('A', 'path')
C = A.B
```

This is quite unhandy with long paths and module names. Is there an easier way? Is there A way, where the module is not added to the local variables (no A)?

Comment: So just to clarify; you have, for example, a library package/module in /usr/local/sbin and you want to import that to a script that is in /home/You/? Or something similiar?

Comment: Not quite. I want to import a package from a parent directory while this package is also found in the python path (different version) and a normal import would always lead to an import of the version that is found in the python path.

Answer (score 0):

If you just don't want `A` to be visible at a global level, you could stick the import (`imp.load_source`) inside a function.  If you actually don't want a module object at all in the local scope, you can do that too, but I wouldn't recommend it.

If module `A` is a python source file you could read in the file (or even just the relevant portion that you want) and run an exec on it.

#### source.py

```
MY_GLOBAL_VAR = 1

def my_func():
    print 'hello'
```

Let's say you have some code that wants `my_func`

```
path = '/path/to/source.py'
execfile(path)

my_func()
# 'hello'
```

Be aware that you're also going to get anything else defined in the file (like `MY_GLOBAL_VAR`).  Again, this will work, but I wouldn't recommend it

- Someone looking at your code won't be able to see where `my_func` came from.
- You're essentially doing the same thing as a `from A import *` import, which is generally frowned upon in python, because , you could be importing all sorts of things into your namespace that you didn't want. And even if it works now, if the source code changes, it could import names that shadow your own global symbols.
- It's potentially a security hole, since you could be exec'ing an untrusted source file.
- It's way more verbose than a regular python import.